# Is $\mathbb{Z}/3\otimes \mathbb{Z}[1/2]=\mathbb{Z}/3$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

The title says all.

Is it true that $\mathbb{Z}/3\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}[1/2]=\mathbb{Z}/3$?

I know that $\mathbb{Z}/2\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}[1/2]=0$ because $1\otimes 1=2\otimes \frac{1}{2}=0\otimes \frac{1}{2}=0$.

Comment: If you have an arbitrary element of the form $\bar a\otimes b/2^c$, can you always find something of the form $\bar x\otimes 1$ that it is equivalent to?

Comment: Oh.. I don't think so.

Comment: x @user: Then can you provide an example of some $\bar x\otimes b/2^c$ that does _not_ have an equivalent $\bar x\otimes 1$?

Comment: Well, I think that $1\otimes \frac{1}{2^c}$ cannot be equivalent to $x\otimes 1$ but I don't know how to prove this.

Comment: $2$ is invertible in $\mathbb{Z}/3$

Comment: @user156937: In the case $c=0$ you automatically have equivalence there, so you'll need to pick a particular $c$ before you can even hope to show it is not equivalent.

Comment: I see, $1\otimes \frac{1}{2}=4\otimes \frac{1}{2}=2\otimes 1$ and $1\otimes  \frac{1}{2^2}=1\otimes 1$. In general, $1\otimes \sum \frac{a_i}{2^i}=\sum a_i2^i\otimes 1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z\otimes_\mathbf Z \mathbf Z\Bigl[\dfrac12\Bigr]$ is the module of fractions of the $\mathbf Z$-module $\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z$ with respect to the multiplicative system $\bigl\{1,2,2^2,\dots,2^n,\dots\bigr\}$. As multiplication by $2$ in $\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z$ is invertible (it's the same as multiplication by $-1$), we obtain nothing new adding powers of $2$ as denominators.

Explicitly:
\begin{align*}
x\otimes\frac1{2^n}=\begin{cases}2^n x\otimes\dfrac1{2^n}=x\otimes\dfrac{2^n}{2^n}= x\otimes1&\text{if $n$ is even},\\
2^{n+1} x\otimes\dfrac1{2^n}=2x\otimes\dfrac{2^n}{2^n}= 2x\otimes1&\text{if $n$ isodd.}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

*Variant:*

As $\mathbf Z\Bigl[\dfrac12\Bigr]\simeq \mathbf Z[T]/(2T-1)$, we have:
\begin{align*}\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z\otimes_\mathbf Z \mathbf Z\Bigl[\dfrac12\Bigr]&\simeq \mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z\otimes_\mathbf Z\mathbf Z[T]/(2T-1)\\&\simeq\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z[T]/(-T-1)\simeq\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z[T]/(T+1) \simeq\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z. \end{align*}